# bessel j asymtopic equality

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, bessel-functions

The following asymptotic expression for the Bessel function holds according to Abramowitz and Stegun:

$$ J_\nu(z) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}} \left(\cos\left(z - \frac{\nu\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4}\right) + \mathrm{e}^{|\operatorname{Im}(z)|} O(|z|^{-1})\right)$$

Does equality just straight up hold here, or are there some size conditions I need to worry about?

Comment: The conditions are that $\nu\in \mathbb{C}$ is fixed, $z$ is bounded away from $0$, and $|\arg z|\le \pi-\delta<\pi$. See https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.7.ii

Comment: ok thank you! this answers my question